# Какой смысле использовать Observable?

Tags: java, android

Какой смысле использовать Observable и Observer
Если есть AsyncTask. Там тоже есть конечный метод, промежуточный и метод перед запуском класса...

Comment: Вы какие Observable имеете в виду, из `java.util` или из `rxJava`?

Comment: @rjhdby, А что разве в rxJava не java.util Oberv используется?. Принцип там ведь одинаковый...

`На ваш вопрос мой ответ такой: java.util`

Comment: @pavlofff, Я понимаю, но ведь функционал один и тот же. Я хочу понять в каких случаях нужно использовать AsyncTask, а в каких Observer.

Comment: @pavlofff, а кажется понял. Хорошая однако вещь. но ведь есть для это BroadCast, broadCast ведь также прослушивает на изменение чего - то и если что то изменилось то вызывается.

Comment: Ок спасибо понял

Comment: @pavlofff не могли бы оформить выдержку из вашей беседы в ответ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что `Observer` и `AsyncTask` выполняют совершенно разные задачи и никакой речи о их взаимозаменяемости не идет, хотя бы у них обоих и есть какие то методы для действий в начале, в процессе выполнения и при завершении операции.

[`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) - это класс-обертка из фреймворка Android, предназначенный для выполнения параллельных операций в другом потоке, с возможностью взаимодействия с основным потоком.

[`Observer`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) (наблюдатель) - это поведенческий паттерн проектирования, предназначенный для уведомления о изменении состояния в наблюдаемом объекте (например изменились данные и их нужно обработать). При этом инициатором сигнала является сам наблюдаемый объект, а классы, подписанные на уведомления от наблюдаемого объекта получат этот сигнал.

В фреймворке Android ближе к `Observer` по принципу действия находится [`BroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html) (широковещательные сообщения) - данный класс реализует  поведенческий паттерн проектирования [издатель-подписчик](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).
Разница между ними в моменте подачи сигнала ( вообще бродкаст это улучшенный обсервер). Если `Observer` реагирует на изменение состояния наблюдаемого объекта и связан с ним, то `Broadcast` может извещать о чем угодно - это рассылка сообщений в эфир всем заинтересованным в этой рассылке.

Отвлеченно, на живых примерах, `AsyncTask` можно сравнить с многополосной дорогой - у нас много груза и мы можем отправлять грузовики одновременно по нескольким полосам, чтобы быстрее доставить весь груз.

`Observer` с сигнализацией в машине. Сама сигнализация это Observer машины, вы - Observable, подписчик на события сигналки через брелок от нее. Когда состояние машины изменяется (кто то пытается ее прибрать себе) вы получаете уведомление об этом печальном событии и можете действовать, спасая свое добро.

`Broadcast` - с радиостанцией. Ни кто иной, а сам президент нашей Родины, придумал очень важный указ, его зачитали по радио и тогда заинтересованные лица тут же смогли исполнять указания, так как они все время слушают это радио.

Как видите, все они имеют свои особенные функции и каким то образом не могут заменять друг друга, особенно дорога и сигнализация :)